# Google cloud platform DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN using 3rd party domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I created a small Flask script which I can easily push into GCP and it is viewable on example.appspot.com. I have also bought a custom domain via hostpoint.ch and set all A/AAAA/CNAME DNS records to values in GCP > Settings > Custom domains as described in the tutorial

I did this a long time ago so there is not a problem with propagating of DNS settings across the internet

The error message shown when accessing my custom domain is DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

Are there any other settings I should change?

Comment: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` often indicates problems on client side: your browser, computer/device, network, internet provider, etc. Try alternatives for them, if any of them works then the issue is likely not with your GAE app or its settings.

Comment: Most likely your DNS settings are wrong. Make sure that you created each entry correctly.